# Carry of multiplication in base k

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm trying to implement a library of big numbers and I'm stuck with multiplication. The issue is not in finding a good algorithm (Karastuba will be fine), but in a way to compute carry of two numbers in base $k$.

Suppose I want to compute the product of two numbers $A$ and $B$ that are in base $k$. Suppose also that all the computations I can do are modulo $k$.

With these suppositions, I know that when doing computation $A\times B$ the result is $A\times B\mod k$.

I want to know how can we compute the carry of the multiplication without having to compute the exact result (because since we work modulo $k$, it's not possible to do the exact computation).

In a first attempt, I suppose that $k$ is even and I express $A$ and $B$ in base $\frac{k}{2}$, with that new representation I can compute the product of $A$ and $B$ and I'm sure that the digits can be represented in base $k$.

Now I want to be more generic and work with basis that are also odd. One possibility is to compute $A \times B$ as $B$ sums of $A$ and sum the carries during the computation but that would be very inefficient.

Can somebody help me finding an efficient way to compute the carry of the product ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that, working with large numbers, your approach to even numbers will give you the numerical space you're looking for. $\left(\frac k2\right)^2 $, or even $\left(\frac k4\right)^2 $, is not necessarily usually going to be less than say $2k$.

You can compute intermediate sums using a doubling process and then add appropriate values according to the binary representation of multiplier. For example, computing $45 \times 78 \bmod 203$:
$$ \begin{align}
45 \times 2 &= 90\\
45 \times 4 &= 90 \times 2 = 180\\
45 \times 8 &= 180 \times 2 =360 \equiv 157\\
45 \times 16 &\equiv 157 \times 2 = 314 \equiv 111\\
45 \times 32 &\equiv 111 \times 2 = 222 \equiv 19\\
45 \times 64 &\equiv 19 \times 2 = 38\\
45 \times 72 &\equiv 38+157 = 195\\
45 \times 76 &\equiv 195+180 \equiv 172\\
45 \times 78 &\equiv 172+90 = 262 \equiv 59\\
\end{align}$$

...all calcs $\bmod 203$. Note that $78 = 64+8+4+2$ which is the basis of the final three lines there. You also have the option of working in the "negative space", as I quietly did in the last-but-one line there - I used $195 \equiv -8$ rather than calculate the original sum.